# Using underscore.js with rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, underscore.js

I've been looking at **underscore.js** and wanted to add it to my rails project. I'm already using jQuery. Is there a best practice when it comes to using these two libraries together? Also, how do you deal with jQuery objects with underscore? Do you use jquery to select a bunch of elements, then run them through **underscore**?

Answer (score 1):

You can either manually include the underscore js file in your assets, or you can use this gem:

https://github.com/rweng/underscore-rails

Underscore works well with Javascript collections and objects of any kind, so the functions do work well with jQuery objects.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use it without `underscore-rails` gem. It is very useless.

It produce nothing but new dependency for the project.

There is no reason to scare using the `underscore.js` directly.

Comment: The gem manages the dependency for you, rather than including underscore.js directly in your repository and having to download a new version when you want updates.

Comment: @webjprgm That's highly dependent on how often the gem's maintainer does this for you.